# Password manager that supports two-page logins and that keeps accounts active (by logging in and out automatically)

Tags: windows-10, password-manager

I want an affordable password manager to do these things:

- run on Windows 10
- log into websites that receive the password on a second page (after you enter your email address).  Yahoo, Hotmail, and Gmail all require a click after you enter your password.
- log into all your email addresses and log you out if you want to just keep the account active

Which password manager would be best for me?